# I'm building a simple lottery contract with help of react but getting error in the webpage

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, web3js

I'm getting an error in my webpage:

> Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also
> see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract
> you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number.

[image]

App.js

```
import React, {
    Component
}
from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import web3 from './web3';
import lottery from './lottery';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            manager: ''
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call();

        this.setState({
            manager
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
             <div>
              <h2> Lottery contract</h2>
              <p>this contract if managed by {this.state.manager}</p>
             </div> 
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Lottery.js

```
import web3 from './web3';

const address = '0xB722A2E673c55F8cD0B781f0683FDa70c46e3183';

const abi = [
    {"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"manager","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"pickWinner","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getPlayers","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address[]"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"enter","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"players","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}];

export default new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

node deploy.js

```
  attmepting to deploy
 [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"manager","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"pickWinner","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getPlayers","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address[]"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"enter","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"players","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}]
 deployed to  0xB722A2E673c55F8cD0B781f0683FDa70c46e3183
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message and it was because my metamask wasn't on the Rinkeby network....once I switched over, it worked.